# Correct way of reading/parsing data with functions from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In our tsx files:

```
export const DefaultDataFields = [
    {
        caption: "Vol",
        dataField: "volume",
        dataType: "number",
        customizeText: commaSeparatedNumber
    }, 
    {
        caption: "OP Rate",
        dataField: "op_rate-calculatedMetric",
        dataType: "number",
        calculateSummaryValue: opRate,
        areaIndex: 6
    },.... ]
```

where **commaSeparatedNumber**,**opRate** - are functions used in runtime for formatting output and are defined in tsx.
Now, suppose we have this object/var as input (read as json- from file), what is the correct way to parse and form the fields ?

**JSON**

```
doc:[{
        caption: "Vol",
        dataField: "volume",
        dataType: "number",
        customizeText: <commaSeparatedNumber> // unsure about this field??
    }, 
    {
        caption: "OP Rate",
        dataField: "op_rate-calculatedMetric",
        dataType: "number",
        calculateSummaryValue: <opRate>, // unsure about this field??
        areaIndex: 6
    },..]
```

Sample JSON to give idea. Please ignore if syntax is incorrect.

*PS- I know about json parsing(serialize/deserialize). 
I am mainly concerned about how to serialize function-fields and bind them to function definitions in code.*

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, do you mean square brackets `docs: [...]`?

Comment: You can not use functions in JSON like that, so it is rather unclear to me what you actually want to achieve here.

Comment: I know we can't use functions in JSON. I wish to keep function in code(tsx) and bind fields to function. I wish to know how can I achieve it.

Comment: You can do that by doing `if-else` on the string in the JSON document and replacing that with the appropriate function - basically write a custom parser. As been noted before - your JSON is not valid, keys must be strings.

Comment: Are the functions always going to be *the same*? As in something like `this.value.toFixed(3)` or whatever working only within the context of the object? Because if so, it seems better to define actual objects of your own that consume this as part of their constructor and then initialise themselves with the values provided. You can have the methods defined *on* those objects, so you don't have multiple copies in memory and it's uniform and easy to maintain.

Comment: Yes functions are kind of same as in - _format(this.value)_. These functions are invoked by a different liabrary(to be exact - during rendering).

Comment: So...the functions in your JSON are not even pure? Then if you were to deseralise them, not only would you be polluting the runtime with many copies of the same code, that code won't even work reliably unless you've the same library exposed to where you'd be doing the deserealisation. I think you can see how this is opening a can of worms here - in order to deserealise the code, you have to be able to run the code. And if you have *that* capability, you should be able to just avoid deserealising functions and construct new object getting the benefit of prototype and such.

Comment: As mentioned by the commenters above, your intention is a bit unclear. Do you want to store which function to use **in json** for each record? Or do you want to store the functions themselves as code?

Comment: To clarify, I dont wish to store function in JSON (no deserialization of function @VLAZ). I just want to store which function to use from code in json parsed. Hope it answers @LexWebb.

Comment: @VLAZ, No serialisation of function is intended. Function to reside in code. And the function is pure as in _format(this.value)_. Am I missing def. of pure function here?

Comment: If it relies on anything outside, it's impure. For exampe `(a, b) => a + b` is pure - always produces the same result. The output of `(a, b) => something(a, b)` relies on `something` as external state. If you're not storing the source of a function then it's not really clear to me what you actually store in your payload nor what the result should look like. I assumed you were talking about deserealising source into runtime functions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yes the functions are indeed not pure. As @LexWebb pointed out, I wish to store function to be used for json record and the function is defined in code. Final aim is to somehow bind actual function to those JSON record as originally present. i.e. form data object with ```customizeText: commaSeparatedNumber``` from the JSON.

Comment: In that case i would keep a second property inside your object with the name of the function to use. So when you parse your JSON, you can map back over the list, find which function each object needs and inject your functions from there.

Comment: In short, deserealise json to object and map property(_customizeText/calculateSummaryValue_ in above case) to function with if-else or switch. Right?